# Permanently storing arrays Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

so I've written a code that iterates through several hundred CSV files, and then stores the last element of each into a new array.

```
 module Example
   @array = []
   def example(file_names) #where file_names is an array of strings for the csv files
     file_names.each { |x|
       @array << (CSV.parse open("#{x}.csv").read)[-1] if File.exists?("{x}.csv") == true }
     return @array
   end
 end
```

Executing this code can take some time, and I want to be able to refer to this newly-created array in other methods without having to run this code again. Is there a way to permanently store the @array variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on just how permanent you want your results to be. If you just don't want to parse the CSV files for the lifetime of your program, then you can simply cache the result in a member variable (as you are with @array), and only execute your code if that array is empty for example:

```
module Example       
    def example(file_names)
        # ||= will only calculate a result if @array is nil, otherwise
        # it will return the saved value
        @array ||= file_names.map { |x| CSV.parse open("#{x}.csv").read)[-1] if File.exists?("{x}.csv") }
    end
 end
```

If you want your work to be saved in-between executions of the program you can try saving your results to a (single) file and reading it back in, using perhaps on of the following:

- JSON: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html
- YAML: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html
- Marshal: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Marshal.html

  - See mu-is-too-short's comment for some of the drawbacks of using Marshal

Comment: Marshal is a poor choice for this sort of thing. The binary format is dependent on the Ruby version and there's no way to read formats that don't match your Ruby version.